# OpenGL project mouse coordinate point to ground plane point

Tags: python, qt, math, opengl, pyside2

I'm trying to write a function which would translate mouse position to a coordinate point on XOZ(ground plane) to draw a geometry there.
The problem is: the formula doesn't seem right. There's a camera point (0, 0, 0, 1) multiplied by viewmatrix, which results in a (0, 0, 0) point. I've already tried to use `camEye` from `lookAt()` matrix as a point but it doesn't work. How should I implement it?

Here's a code snippet:

```py
    def screenToWorld(self, mouse_pos: QtGui.QVector2D):
        tmp = QtGui.QVector4D(
            2.0 * mouse_pos.x() / self.width() - 1.0,
            -2.0 * mouse_pos.y() / self.height() + 1.0,
            -1.0, 1.0
        )
        i_tmp = QtGui.QVector4D(
            (tmp * self.camera.projectionMatrix.inverted()[0]).toVector2D(), -1.0, 0.0
        )
        direction = QtGui.QVector3D(
            (i_tmp * self.camera.viewMatrix.inverted()[0]).toVector3D().normalized()
        )
        cam_pos = QtGui.QVector3D(
            (QtGui.QVector4D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) * self.camera.viewMatrix.inverted()[0]).toVector3D()
        )

        normal = QtGui.QVector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        t = -QtGui.QVector3D.dotProduct(cam_pos, normal) / QtGui.QVector3D.dotProduct(direction, normal)
        result = cam_pos + direction * t

        return result
```

Here's a picture what I'd like to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Can you supply sample input and desired result?

Comment: @Yunnosch, as an input we get screen mouse position in a screen space and we should get a point of intersection of a ray from input point with a XOZ plane

Comment: You've set the viewspace z coordinate of the point on the ray to a constant value of 
-1.0. Change it to `i_tmp = QtGui.QVector4D((tmp * self.camera.projectionMatrix.inverted()[0]).toVector3D(), 0.0)`

Comment: @Rabbid76, hmm i've changed it, but result is still QVector3D(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)

Comment: @Artem what are the values for `cam_pos`, `direction` and t`? Are they all 0? If the ray is in the x-z plane of the world then there is no intersection point.

Comment: @Rabbid76, direction is not 0, but cam_pos and t get 0. Actually, I've been trying  to follow this guy, and it seems like he has got everything work. (https://youtu.be/rXN4A7x8pXo?t=665)

Comment: @Artem See the formula `result = cam_pos + direction * t`. If `t` and `direction` is 0, then `result` is 0 too. If the x any z component of `direction` is 0, then the ray is in the ground plane of the world (parallel to the ground plane). You can not intersect a plane with a ray that is in the plane.

Comment: @Rabbid76, yeah I see. The thing is, if the camera is 0, then t is 0 too because of the dot product: (0,0,0) * (0,1,0) = 0. As I mentioned, setting camera pos as multiply of a vec4(0) by mat4 seems to be an incorrect formula. I would try to rewrite it, but the intersting thing that it worked for the guy i'm following to.

Comment: @Artem No the formula is correct, but if the camera position is on the ground, then the ray is in the ground plane. Your eyes are on the ground and you look along the ground., so you cannot finde an intersection point.

Comment: @Rabbid76, excuse me for my dumbness)), but - If I get it right, to make this thing work I should change cam_pos from 0 to another vector, right? If yes, then it will look along the ground anyway, won't it?

Comment: @Artem The camera position has to have a y component.

Comment: @Rabbid76, what's that component? Actual camera hight? Or what's that value should be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222667/discussion-between-artem-and-rabbid76).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it! The problem was in incorrect camera position.
As I've read, we can get it from inverted `view matrix`. Elements with indices `41, 42, 43` will be our camera position, so I wrote a class variable updating each time camera moves:

```py
self.__camPos = self.__viewMatrix.inverted()[0].column(3).toVector3D()
```

After that, everything works like a charm:

```py
    def createRayDir(self, mouse_pos: QVector2D):
        # Normalized Coordinate Space
        x = 2.0 * mouse_pos.x() / self.__viewportSize.x() - 1
        y = 2.0 * mouse_pos.y() / self.__viewportSize.y() - 1

        clip = QVector4D(x, -y, -1.0, 1.0)
        proj = QVector4D((clip * self.__projectionMatrix.inverted()[0]).toVector2D(), -1.0, 0.0)

        return (proj * self.__viewMatrix).toVector3D().normalized()

    def getRayGridIntersecton(self, mouse_pos: QVector2D):
        ray_dir = self.createRayDir(mouse_pos)

        n = QVector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        t = -QVector3D.dotProduct(self.__camPos, n) / QVector3D.dotProduct(ray_dir, n)

        return self.__camPos + ray_dir * t
```